# Android - Set a Local Image to an img element in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-contentprovider

I am passing a local file through Javascript to set an img source and I cannot get it working.
The javascript to set the path is

```
<img src='" + the_payload.image + "' width='" + (cellWidth()-20) + "' />
```

The String that I am sending is the complete file path:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.newvisioninteractive.android.myapp/files/c87eba4a-5349-4a55-baec-cc573a5f7571-thumb.png
```

I saw a post about ContentProviders and ParcelFileDescriptors but could not get that to work either.

This is for a Calendar View that displays images on certain days. It works fine when I pass in a static image, just not a local one.

Also, I have set

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Do I need to set any other Permissions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in extending the ContentProvider class and Overriding the openFile(Uri, String) method

```
package com.packagename.provider;
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider { 
     @Override
     public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode){
        URI fileURI = URI.create( "file://" + uri.getPath() );
        File file = new File( fileURI );

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = null;
        try {
            parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e( TAG, "Error finding: " + fileURI + "\n" + e.toString() );
        }

        return parcel;
     }
}
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml file include

```
 <provider
        android:name=".provider.MyProvider"
        android:authorities="com.packagename" />
```

You can then access your files which would normally be

```
 file://sdcard/Android/data/com.packagename/image.jpg
```

by using

```
 content://com.packagename/sdcard/Android/data/com.packagename/image.jpg
```

So essentially **replace file:// with content://com.packagename**

Answer (score 0):

try using file:///android_assets/image.png and place images in the android assets

Comment: They are files that are downloaded from a Web Service and are saved onto the SDcard thus they are created dynamically and not there to place in the assets folder to begin with

Comment: are you using lazyloader to download files?